# Is compression/decompression of gzip data transparent in Hadoop/PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I read somewhere that Hadoop has a built-in support for compression and decompression but I guess it is about mapper output (by setting some properties)?

I wonder if there is any particular PIG load/store functions I can use for reading compressed data or outputting data as compressed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PigStorage handles compressed input by examining the file names:

- *.bz2 / *.bz - `org.apache.pig.bzip2r.Bzip2TextInputFormat`
- Everything else uses `org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat`
  -- This extends `o.a.h.mapreduce.TextinputFormat` which can handle .gz and zippy files if you have the codecs installed

Output is handled via some properties:

- `output.compression.enabled` - true / false
- `output.compression.codec` - the class name of the codec to use (`org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec` for gzip)

If you're feeling up to it, digging through the PigStorage.java may be of interest to you

Comment: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449317881/8dot-making-pig-fly/id2907215 also gives some more details about intermediate compression