# Apache Pig: Load a file that shows fine using hadoop fs -text

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I have files that are named part-r-000[0-9][0-9] and that contain tab separated fields. I can view them using `hadoop fs -text part-r-00000` but can't get them loaded using pig.

What I've tried:

```
x = load 'part-r-00000';
dump x;
x = load 'part-r-00000' using TextLoader();
dump x;
```

but that only gives me garbage. How can I view the file using pig?

What might be of relevance is that my hdfs is still using CDH-2 at the moment.
Furthermore, if I download the file to local and run `file part-r-00000` it says `part-r-00000: data`, I don't know how to unzip it locally.

Comment: I believe your first `load` uses PigStorage, but maybe you can double check by being explicit, `x = LOAD 'part-r-00000' USING USING PigStorage('\t')`.  When you download the file locally, if you view it (i.e. `tail`), is it garbage/binary?  Can you give example of code that generated this data?

Comment: Using PigStorage explicitly gives the same result. Downloading to local (using -get or -copyToLocal) the file is not readable, i. e. binary/garbage (less or tail). I'll try to find the code that created these files and report back.

Comment: It looks like the file has been stored as a sequence file. I've been able to extract lines from it using an user defined load function. Is there a simpler way than using the udf?

Comment: I updated my answer with sample code related to sequencefile's. hope that helps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [HDFS Documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.17.2/hdfs_shell.html#text), `hadoop fs -text <file>` can be used on "zip and TextRecordInputStream" data, so your data may be in one of these formats.

If the file was compressed, normally Hadoop would add the extension when outputting to HDFS, but if this was missing, you could try testing by unzipping/ungzipping/unbzip2ing/etc locally.  It appears Pig should do this decompressing automatically, but may require the file extension be present (e.g. part-r-00000.zip) -- [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896584/is-compression-decompression-of-gzip-data-transparent-in-hadoop-pig).

I'm not too sure on the TextRecordInputStream.. it sounds like it would just be the default method of Pig, but I could be wrong.  I didn't see any mention of LOAD'ing this data via Pig when I did a quick Google.

**Update:**
Since you've discovered it is a sequence file, here's how you can load it using PiggyBank:

```
-- using Cloudera directory structure:
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar
--REGISTER /home/hadoop/lib/pig/piggybank.jar
DEFINE SequenceFileLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.SequenceFileLoader();


-- Sample job: grab counts of tweets by day
A = LOAD 'mydir/part-r-000{00..99}' # not sure if pig likes the {00..99} syntax, but worth a shot 
    USING SequenceFileLoader AS (key:long, val:long, etc.);
```

Comment: `{00..99}` didn't work, so I'm simply using `*` instead. Afterwards the line can be read using `B = FOREACH A GENERATE flatten(STRSPLIT (val, '\t')) AS (etc.)`, since SequenceFileLoader returns only two columns.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to manipulate (read/write) sequence files with `Pig` then you can give a try to Twitter's [Elephant-Bird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird) as well.

You can find [here](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/Readme.md#hadoop-sequencefiles-and-pig) examples how to read/write them.

If you use custom Writables in you sequence file then you can implement a custom converter by extending [AbstractWritableConverter](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/pig/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/util/AbstractWritableConverter.java) .

Note, that `Elephant-Bird` needs to have an installed [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) in your machine.
Before building it, make sure that it is using the correct Thrift version you have and also provide the correct path of the Thrift executable in its [pom.xml](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/pom.xml):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.thrift.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-thrift-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.10</version>
  <configuration>
    <thriftExecutable>/path_to_thrift/thrift</thriftExecutable>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```