# ElephantBird package build failure:

Tags: apache-pig, elephantbird

I downloaded ElephantBird source and tried to build by running "mvn package" but I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.igor-petruk.protobuf:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.4:run (default) on project elephant-bird-core: Unable to find 'protoc' -> [Help 1]
```

I am using mvn version 3.0.3 and I tried in the Mac and Ubuntu but I got the same error.

EDIT1:

Thanks to Lorand's comments, I resolved the above problem by upgrading the protocol buffer. I also installed Thrift 0.7.0 but now I am having another compilation failure during elephant-pig build:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project elephant-bird-pig: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: [ERROR] /root/elephant-bird/pig/src/test/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/util/TestThriftNameWritableConverter.java:[12,26] invalid inferred types for W; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
```

Comment: It looks like the error is due to some Java generic code syntax in the unit test code.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have previously installed `Protocol Buffers` (apt-get install protobuf-compiler) and `Thrift`. You also have to set Thrift's location in Elephant-bird's pom.xml.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12301954

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting a different error message: [0] Inside the definition for plugin 'protobuf-maven-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <inputDirectories>VALUE</inputDirectories>
</configuration>

-OR-

on the command line, specify: '-DinputDirectories=VALUE'

Comment: Would this error be caused by protocol buffer version difference? pom.xml says 2.3.0 but the version I installed is 2.2.0

Comment: I installed v2.3 and had no such issue. Try to do so to see whether it helps

Comment: @kee , were you able to solve this problem ? I made the changes to pom.xml by putting absolute path of thrift executable , I'm still hitting the same error.

Comment: I gave up and went for v1.2.4 of EB instead :(

Answer (score 0):

Use Java 7 JDK to fix the Java compilation error.

Comment: I don't have any plan to revisit this package soon but next time I will definitely try.