# Elephant-bird build failure

Tags: thrift, elephantbird

As I wanted to use Elephant bird to read/write JSON files in PIG, downloaded EB for Mac

```
git clone git://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird.git
```

and tried to build using

```
mvn package
```

and the build failed as below,

```
[INFO] --- protobuf-maven-plugin:0.4:run (default) @ elephant-bird-core ---
[INFO] Protobuf dependency version 2.4.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Elephant Bird ..................................... SUCCESS [1.670s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hadoop Compatibility ................ SUCCESS [3.148s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Core ................................ FAILURE [0.927s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading2 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hive ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Mahout .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird RCFile .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Lucene .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig Lucene .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Examples ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.igor-petruk.protobuf:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.4:run (default) on project elephant-bird-core: Unable to find 'protoc' -> [Help 1]
```

I have checked this link [ElephantBird package build failure:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468811/elephantbird-package-build-failure) and downloaded thrift 0.9 and tried specifying the absolute path in pom.xml

Any suggestions please on How to get it running.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an apt-get based system, try installing the `libprotobuf-java` package. You could also install version 2.4.1 from source http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/detail?name=protobuf-2.4.1.tar.gz.

https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/wiki/Build-errors mentions this error.