# Not able to filter data using Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using Hadoop 1.0.3, Pig 0.11.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. In the part-m-00000 file in HDFS the content is as below

> training@BigDataVM:~/Installations/hadoop-1.0.3$ bin/hadoop fs -cat /user/training/user/part-m-00000
>   1,Praveen,20,India,M
>   2,Prajval,5,India,M
>   3,Prathibha,15,India,F

I am loading it into a bag and then filtering it as below.

> Users1 = load '/user/training/user/part-m-00000' as (user_id, name, age:int, country, gender);
>   Fltrd = filter Users1 by age <= 16;

But, when I dump the **Users1** 5 records are shown in the console. But, dumping **Fltrd** will fetch no records.

> dump Fltrd;

The below warning is shown in the Pig console

> 2013-02-24 16:19:40,735 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD 12 time(s).

Looks like I have done some simple mistake, but couldn't figure out what it is. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't defined any load function, Pig will use [PigStorage](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html) in which the
default delimiter is **'\t'**.

If part-m-00000 is a textfile then try to set the delimiter to ',' :

```
Users1 = load '/user/training/user/part-m-00000' using PigStorage(',') 
  as (user_id, name, age:int, country, gender);
```

If it's a SequenceFile then have a look at Dolan's or [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12301954) answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286845/apache-pig-load-a-file-that-shows-fine-using-hadoop-fs-text/12301954) question.

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm. Not getting some other problem in the script :(